# Как сохранять текст, введенный в InputField, при переходе на другую сцену в Юнити?

Tags: c#, unity3d

пытаюсь сделать мобильное приложение на юнити. Задумка такова: пользователь тапает на поле с вводом текста, вводит что-то, а это "что-то" должно остаться лежать в инпутфилде мертвым грузом, даже если пользователь перейдет на другую сцену. В юнити тусуюсь второй день, но на протяжении суток так и не смог найти решение своего вопроса. Нашел способ, чтобы сохранять значения полей, но, при переходе на другие сцены, они теряются.

```
[SerializeField] InputField field;
[SerializeField] Text myText;
string input_text;

public void GetAndLoadText()
{
    input_text = field.text;
    myText.text = input_text;
    Debug.Log("trulala");
}
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в каком направлении двигаться, чтобы закрыть эту проблему. Фотку "концепта" прилагаю [image: недо-концепт]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### PLAYERPREFS

[***Документация***](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PlayerPrefs.html)

При старте сцены(Метод Start в каком-то ведущем скрипте) вы можете использовать `текст.текст = PlayerPrefs.GetString("НазваниеДанных");`.

Чтобы эти самые данные были - нужно использовать `PlayerPrefs.SetString("НазваниеДанных", текст.текст)`. Текст можно взять из field.text

В случае, если я вас не правильно понял - пишите в комментарий к этому вопросу, а если же помог - отметьте ответ правильным, нажав на галочку